# How to read all files in a folder inside a package in an ear

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, directory, jboss

I have this following folder structure inside my ear

```
-proj1
  - src
     -loader.java
-proj2
  - folder1
     -1.json
     -2.json
```

So I have to load these json files one by one in loader.java file to perform my operation. Project 1 has the reference of project2. I have deployed my ear in jboss6.3 eap server.

I have tried using the classloader to point to the directory, but the directory it gives is something else, but if I specify the file name directly to the loader it loads perfectly.

```
   InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folder1/1.json");
```

It loads correctly but I dont know to get the list of files in that folder directory